# How do i resolve the error "read: Illegal option -d ". i wish to run it under sh. is there any alternative route

Tags: bash, sh

this is my code. i am checking for any modification in files/ filesystem after its last scan.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo " " > new_files_log.txt

find . -type f  -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d ' ' file; do
    if ! grep -Fxq "$(stat -c '%Y  :   %n' "$file")" log.txt
    then
        echo "$(stat -c '%Y  :   %n' "$file")" &>> log.txt
        echo "$(stat -c '%Y  :   %n' "$file")" >> new_files_log.txt
    fi
    echo "$(stat -c '%Y  :   %n' "$file")" &>> log.txt
done
```

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using? And if you want to use `NUL` as the delimiter, the `-r` parameter should be an empty string, not a space.

Comment: `sh` is the POSIX shell, whose `read` built-in does not support `-d`.

Comment: Why `echo "$(...anything...)" >>file` instead of just `...anything... >>file`?

Comment: Also, `&>>` is a bashism; it's not guaranteed to work with `/bin/sh` any more than `read -d` is (which is to say, not in the slightest). If you want a feature, you need to use a shell that supports that feature, full-stop.

Comment: Also, `read -r -d ' '` is **completely different** from `read -r -d ''`, which is the practice you were presumably trying to follow (aka, the only correct way to read `find -print0` output in bash); they don't do the same thing at all.

Comment: Also, note that `stat -c` isn't guaranteed by POSIX either, so platforms that only give you a basic `/bin/sh` may not support the `stat` functionality you want.

Comment: `find . -type f  -exec archive "{}" \;` . Decompose your problem into simple parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reliably/portably run a script with `/bin/sh`, you can only use features that the POSIX sh specification guarantees -- which for `read` means those features documented at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html. `read -d` is not one of those features.

However, there's an alternate way to get arbitrary filenames out of `find` into your shell; you can pass them on the command line with `-exec` instead of streaming them NUL-delimited with `-print0`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    fmt=$(stat -c "%Y  :   %n" "$file")
    if ! grep -Fxq "$fmt" log.txt; then
      printf "%s\n" "$fmt" >>new_files_log.txt
    fi
    printf "%s\n" "$fmt" >>log.txt
  done
' _ {} +
```

That said, note that this code (running `grep` over and over, once per line) is **extremely** inefficient, and I wouldn't ever recommend using it for anything. Much more efficient to generate all your output unconditionally, sort it all in one batch, and use `comm` to efficiently merge new and preexisting streams; see [BashFAQ #36](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036).

---

A more efficient solution (to maintain a `new-log.txt` showing files that recently were created, and a `last-log.txt` with all files that existed as of the immediately prior run) might look like:

```
touch last-log.txt # create if not already present
find . -type f -exec stat -c '%Y  :   %n' -- {} + | sort >current-log.txt
comm -13 last-log.txt current-log.txt >new-log.txt
mv current-log.txt last-log.txt
```

Note that this requires `last-log.txt` to be sorted; if you're using a preinitialized file, be sure you maintain that constraint.

Comment: thank you so much !! that was exactly what i  was looking for ...